# HTTP JVM Error - Unable to get document page name

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Xpage Application - In the domino server log, I am getting the error as

HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Unable to get document page name for 7EC37B533FC6F7CE65257BDE0038ECDC

What may be the reason behind of this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the XPages log files in the IBM_Technical_Support folder in the data directory. If you can not get to the XPages log files on the server directly, then use XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF to get easy access to the log files from a browser: http://www.openntf.org/p/XPages%20Log%20File%20Reader

Comment: http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_URLs - do you use links that generate $$OpenDominoDocument.xsp in URL?

Comment: Yes Frantisek Kossuth , I generate the link with "$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp" in URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Form design element associated with the document in question, and bring up the Form Properties infobox. On the second tab, set the "Display XPage instead" option to the page that should load when a document is accessed directly (e.g. via the `$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp` URL syntax. There is a separate property for which XPage should be used whether the document is accessed via the Notes client or via a browser, so if applicable, you can set these to different XPage elements for each context.