# Strange error using Dojo Data Grid in Xpages

Tags: xpages, dojox.grid.datagrid

My Xpage contains header document data at top and a categorized Dojo Data Grid with child documents after it. Normally in any view I set the "At runtime, open selected document using" property to "Xpage associated with the document's form" and then associate the correct Xpage to the form.

I did this on the view containing the header docs. When the document loaded, and when I was not in edit mode, the Dojo Data Grid threw a strange error.

[image]
[image]
If I go into Edit mode on the doc, then the Dojo Data Grid works.

If I change the setting above to EXPLICITLY choose the correct Xpgage to open, then it work.

I don't have a problem changing the setting to be explicit, but I would like to know why it works one way and not the other.

Here is the code from my Rest data source:

```
<xe:restService pathInfo="gridData" id="restService1">
                    <xe:this.service>
                        <xe:viewJsonService
                            viewName="(rstAllRspPCTasks)" var="rstEntry" systemColumns="4">
                            <xe:this.columns>


                                <xe:restViewColumn name="ID">
                                    <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return rstEntry.getColumnValue("ID")}]]></xe:this.value>
                                </xe:restViewColumn>
                                <xe:restViewColumn name="status">
                                    <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return rstEntry.getColumnValue("status")}]]></xe:this.value>
                                </xe:restViewColumn>
                                <xe:restViewColumn name="category">


                                    <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return rstEntry.getColumnValue("category")}]]></xe:this.value>
                                </xe:restViewColumn>
                                <xe:restViewColumn name="title">

                                    <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return rstEntry.getColumnValue("title")}]]></xe:this.value>
                                </xe:restViewColumn>

                            </xe:this.columns>


                            <xe:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:return viewScope.get("ID")}]]></xe:this.keys>
                        </xe:viewJsonService>
                    </xe:this.service>
                </xe:restService>
```

Comment: Can you the include the code for your grid's data source.  I assume you are using a Rest Service.

Comment: Yes, I have posted it above.

Comment: I suspect that when you go to "read" mode then it cannot find the value in your keys.  The viewScope value 'ID' is null causing the error.  Please check that it has a value when in read mode, and see if this fixes your issue.

Comment: That was what I thought, but this occurred even if I took out the filter using the viewScope. Just for kicks I did try what you suggested, and the value did appear, even in view mode only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177187/unable-to-get-document-page-name-for-null

Comment: When you say the "value did appear" do you mean that the viewScope is there either way, and you are still having the issue?